# como eliminar signo �?

Tags: javascript, api, vuetify

hola tengo una llamada en una api que me devuelve esto :"03 Cuotas Sin Inter�s " ,el signo es una e con acento (é) pero me lo devuelve de esa manera , intente con funciones para remplazar ese signo con su letra pero no lo toma , la funcion que implemente es la siguiente :

```
let sinDiacriticos = (function(){
    let de = 'ÁÃÀÄÂÉËÈÊÍÏÌÎÓÖÒÔÚÜÙÛÑÇáãàäâéëèêíïìîóöòôúüùûñç',
         a = 'AAAAAEEEEIIIIOOOOUUUUNCaaaaaeeeeiiiioooouuuunc',
        re = new RegExp('['+de+']' , 'ug');

    return texto =>
        texto.replace(
            re, 
            match => a.charAt(de.indexOf(match))
        );
})();


let prueba1 = '2010 AT34 03 Cierre Cuotas Sin Inter�s';
let prueba2 ="Épico año de mal agüero, sólo Óscar y Ángel ganarán ésta. -Ímpetú Úrsula. ¡Ñañdú corre rápido por ahí!"
console.log(sinDiacriticos(prue1));
console.log(sinDiacriticos(prue2));
```

prueba 1 es el texto que yo le di para formatear el texto y prueba 2 es otro texto aparte que si lo formateo correctamente, alguien sabe como solucionar mi problema?

adjunto imagen para mostrar el texto obtenido de mi api

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mencionas que desde el origen llega así, lo más probable es que tengas un detalle con la codificación. Sería bueno que mostraras cómo obtienes los datos así como también que hagas mención a en dónde se encuentran (si es una base de datos -y de qué tipo-, en disco, etc.), tal vez la solución sea más sencilla de lo que crees.

Comment: ¿cuál es el encoding el API y cuál es el que tienes configurado en tu documento? ¿tienes definido explícitamente el _enconding_ en un tag meta (`<meta charset="utf-8">`)? Si tu API está extrayendo la información de una base de datos, esos datos también tienen una codificación que tal vez no sea UTF-8

Comment: lo obtienes de una base de datos?

Comment: si es asi debes configurarla con un cotejamiento de utf8mb4_general_ci

Answer (score 0):

si es una pagina web, agrega a tu documento html una etiqueta `<meta charset="utf-8">` dentro de la etiqueta head, esto te permitirá poder poner símbolos raros como acentos, la ñ,etc.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<!-- Aqui debe ir tu etiqueta meta -->
<meta charset="UTF-8"> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>tu titulo</title>
</head>
<body>
     tu contenido
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Pero si el problema viene desde la respuesta de la api

Comment: lo obtienes de una base de datos?

Comment: si es asi debes configurarla con un cotejamiento de utf8mb4_general_ci

Comment: No me lo digas a mi, díselo al OP

Comment: a tienes razon me confundi de persona

Answer (score 0):

El problema es la codificación de los caracteres acentuados,

```
Inter�s
```

para resolver esto, dentro del `<head>` de tu archivo .html , define la codificación, en este caso para acentos usa `UTF-8`.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    ...
    ...
</head>
```

Es importante también que asegures tus archivos sean creados con la codificación UTF-8.